# Jmeter - Unable to run 1000 concurrent users per/sec

Tags: java, azure, jmeter, performance-testing, blazemeter

[image]I have been trying to run a performance test using JMeter for 10000 users with a concurrency of 1000 users per/sec and the issue is I never able to hit my throughput of 1000 users on my server which is deployed in Azure. I wanted to know what is the bit which I am doing it wrong and[image] any help is much-appreciated Thanks?

My user defined varibales:

```
users   ${__P(USERS,10)}
seconds ${__P(SECONDS,3600)}
scale   ${__P(SCALE,2)}
env ${__P(ENV,preprod)}
wait    false
```

`jmeter -n -t ./src/test/branchHub/agentAuthentication.jmx -JUSERS=1000 -JSECONDS=5 -JENV=preprod -JSCALE=0.2 -JLOOPS=3 -JPRODUCTS=bill -JCERTINI=1 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=./src/main/resources/certificates/preprodStore.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=performance -Jhttps.use.cached.ssl.context=true -q ./src/test/user.properties -l logs/summary/394output.jtl -e -o logs/reports/394`

This is the console log

16:14:10  Creating summariser 
16:14:10  Created the tree successfully using ./src/test/branchHub/agentAuthentication.jmx
16:14:10  Starting the test @ Fri Jun 28 15:14:10 UTC 2019 (1561734850233)
16:14:10  Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/Heapdump message on port 4445
16:14:32  summary +     17 in 00:00:20 =    0.8/s Avg:  1330 Min:    77 Max:  2174 Err:     1 (5.88%) Active: 7 Started: 20 Finished: 13
16:15:05  summary +     29 in 00:00:30 =    1.0/s Avg:  1596 Min:  1443 Max:  2868 Err:     0 (0.00%) Active: 7 Started: 49 Finished: 42
16:15:05  summary =     46 in 00:00:50 =    0.9/s Avg:  1498 Min:    77 Max:  2868 Err:     1 (2.17%)
16:15:37  summary +     30 in 00:00:30 =    1.0/s Avg:  1674 Min:  1252

Comment: Show the definition of a Thread Group that you created to simulate 1000 users, ideally include the entire test plan.

Comment: "my server which is deployed in Azure": VM, App Service, container, AKS?  What size/capacity?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki as mentioned please find the Test plan attached.

Comment: @user2952161 you haven't attached the test plan, there is no way to tell how did you set up the Thread Groups.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki my bad have attached them now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into `Active: 7` [summarizer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#summariser) output you seem to have not more than 7 active users.

Given you have only 2 [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) and only 3 loops defined under the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) my expectation is that you're simply not achieving the desired concurrency as threads finish requests in ~3 seconds and being shut down while others are not yet started.

Try setting Loop Count to `-1` or tick "Forever" box - this way you should be able to achieve the desired concurrency. Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected/) for more detailed information.

Also make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it might be the case default JMeter setup is not suitable for producing 10000 concurrent users so you will need to tune it for maximum performance. If the tuning will not help - you will have to go for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Thread Group with 1000 threads. Unless your Azure instance has 1000 vCPUs this will lead to excessive [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) and JVM will spend more time switching between the threads instead of doing the work.

Either create a Thread Group with less threads and repeat the test actions within a single thread or add more vCPUs to your instance.